# Best distribution to handle a ratio of counts as a response variable

Tags: distributions, count-data, biostatistics, genetics, ratio

A quick statistics question (apologies for the added biology):

I have two sets of counts (for the expression of two different isoforms of a particular gene), and to generate the response variable in my particular analysis I have taken the ratio of these (Isoform 2 / Isoform 1) for each of 124 individuals. The counts can be modelled with a negative binomial distribution, but I am unsure what distribution to use for these ratios as they are obviously no longer discrete integers.
The test I hope to do is a genotype (coded as 0, 1 or 2) vs isoform-ratio test, across SNPs falling within this gene. The intention is to identify variants that may influence gene splicing such that, say, individuals with genotype 0 have more isoform 1 than 2, and the reverse is seen in individuals with genotype 2 - such that the difference between the ratios is significant.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I should handle this type of analysis?

Cheers!

Comment: Indeed they are.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, it's in your title.

Comment: How do you determine the counts? I ask because you may need to normalise the count data depending on the measurement system

Comment: The count data was generated from RNA sequence data using RSEM [http://www.biomedcentral.com/1471-2105/12/323], the counts being 'the number of alignable fragments derived from an isoform of a given gene'. I used a second program (DESeq2) to normalise (correct for library size), feeding it a table of counts per isoform for each individual (across all genes, not just mine).
I am very much open to other suggestions for normalising count data though! Isoform counts are a little trickier than gene counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some function of `iso2/iso1` is the primary quantity of interest and you're not particularly interested in (or are at least content to condition on) the size of `iso1+iso2`, then a logistic regression analysis might work for you.  In R, something like:

```
mod <- glm(cbind(iso2, iso1) ~ genotype, family=binomial)
```

The linear predictor in this analysis - the logit - represents then how much more `iso2` there is than `iso1`, expressed proportionally.

Comment: Thank you @conjugateprior, I will give that a go! So a binomial distribution is still okay if my response variable is not confined between 0 and 1?
Also, what do you mean by condition on the size of `iso1` + `iso2`?

Comment: A Binomial needs 2 quantities: the parameter representing the probability of a 'head' p, and the 'number of tosses' n.  Its 'response' is (equivalently) either a number k between 0 and n representing that k 'heads' appeared in n 'tosses', or a pair of numbers [k, n-k] indicating k heads and n-k tails. (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution). When n=1 this is a Bernoulli distribution. You'd be saying: "in each of my cases there were n=iso1+iso2 'tosses' of which iso2 came up heads and the rest tails. Larger n makes me more sure about iso2/(iso2+iso1) as an estimate of p"

Comment: The R code above just expresses the response in each case in the [k, n-k] form.  You're *conditioning* on n in the sense that the model assumes that each case i has a response [k_i, n_i-k_i] that is distributed Binomial(p_i, n_i) where p_i is *estimated* but n_i is just plugged in, equal to iso2_i+iso1_i.

Comment: Ahhh yes thank you that makes sense! So in this case the response is a proportion. I will try your glm with my data; from what you have said it sounds as though it will be appropriate. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Right: The response is two counts, but your quantity of interest seems to be a proportion.

Comment: One more question, sorry! Can you suggest a way to do a simple comparison of these proportions between two groups (a group of cases and a group of controls) - I assume a t-test isn't wise?

Comment: If you named a factor or 0/1 coded treatment variable on the right hand side of the model formula then `summary(mod)` will run Wald tests against a zero null and reports z-score, standard error, and p-value for each parameter. `confint(mod)` will generate the corresponding confidence intervals.  Remember that the parameter on the treatment variable is then the effect of treatment vs control on the logit of the response, not the response itself.  Some more detail is [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/dae/logit.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use beta-distribution and beta-regression?

http://www.ime.usp.br/~sferrari/beta.pdf